# Difference between ExtJS and TypeScript

Tags: extjs, typescript

Could you please explain in detail the difference between TypeScript ans ExtJS. Which one is most compatible to use and its advantages?

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: It's the same as asking "What is the difference between Java and Spring", or "What is the difference between C# and Unity". They serve different roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is a *programming language*.

ExtJS is a *JavaScript library*.

They can both be used together.

## More

In fact here is a Sample [TypeScript file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/extjs/ExtJS-tests.ts) that shows how you can use EXTJS with TypeScript.

## More

Learn TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: could you please explain in detail

Comment: I've added two more `more` sections